# Does "CREATE INDEX WITH DROP_EXISTING" use the bufferpool for the recreated index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index, buffer-pool

We have recreate our 4TB clustered index in ouor SQL Server. Even thought we have 1.5TB of memory we still run into the following error message:

"Msg 802, Level 17, State 2, Line 30
There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool"

Nothing else was done on the SQL Server as it is dedicated to this database, which was run in Single User mode.

Does anyone has a good idea, what might have filled up the buffer pool - as far as I know, a recreated index will not be kept in memory, but rather on disk.

Some further information:

> max degree of parallism: 4
>   MaxMemory: a little below 1,5TB
>   Lock Pages in Memory is been activated
>   the index was created with drop existing and MAXDOP-Option set to 1

The purpose was to stop a wild running UNIQUIFIER, which almost reached 2^31-1 due to a limited number of values for the clustered key (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 to be precise) - thus the clustered index key was simply on the partitionKey TINYINT and the internal column UNIQUIFIER.

To repeat a question: Who has some clue as to what might has filled up the buffer pool? Or does an index indeed store the complete recreate in the buffer pool?

One idea was, the LPiM-setting might has caused SQL Server not to page at all - I haven't evaluated that idea yet.

#

Here the database schema:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PCBScheme]
    AS PARTITION [PBCKey]
    TO ( [P0], [P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6], [P7], [P8], [P9], [PRIMARY] )
    -- each Partition holds approximatly 177 million entries, PRIMMARY is empty and doesn't really belongs in here

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PBCKey](TINYINT)
    AS RANGE LEFT
    FOR VALUES (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
      [TableID]      BIGINT    NOT NULL   IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [Other_Columns_1]    INT       NULL
    , [Other_Columns_2]    DATETIME2(7)    NULL
    , [Other_Columns_3]    BINARY(32)      NULL
    , [Other_Columns_4]    VARBINARY(max)  NULL -- regularly 1,5KB in size
    , [...]
    , [PartitionKey] AS (CONVERT(TINYINT,[TableID]%(10),0)) PERSISTED
)  ON [PCBScheme] ([PartitionKey]);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CL_Table__PartitionKey]
    ON [dbo].[Table] (
       [PartitionKey]  -- This is a dumb key to use for a clustered, when the values are only 0-9
    )
    WITH (
         FILLFACTOR              = 100
       , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS        = ON
       , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS         = ON
       , PAD_INDEX               = OFF
       , DROP_EXISTING           = OFF
       , IGNORE_DUP_KEY          = OFF
    ) ON [PCBScheme] ([PartitionKey]); -- this is the CL as it is in Prod right now
```

And here is our recreate-command:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CL_Table__PartitionKey]
    ON [dbo].[Table] (
       [PartitionKey]
    )
    WITH (
         FILLFACTOR              = 100
       , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS        = ON
       , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS         = ON
       , PAD_INDEX               = OFF
       , SORT_IN_TEMPDB          = OFF   -- our TempDB isn't big enough to support this (limited due to disk size)
       , DROP_EXISTING           = ON
       , IGNORE_DUP_KEY          = OFF
       , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF   -- we will set this to ON next time
       , ONLINE                  = OFF   -- OFF is our only option due to the other columsn in the table
       , MAXDOP                  = 1     -- Default is 4, we will try either that or 20 or 19, which will be cores/NUMA node or one less
    ) ON [PCBScheme] ([PartitionKey]);
```

Comment: What are your MIN/MAX memory settings for the SQL Server?  And how much memory is available to Windows and other processes (SSIS, etc) that also need memory? And index rebuilds may use tempdb space, which is also limited, so how much tempdb space do you have and how big is the index?

Comment: I have added our schema above in my initial question. About your other questions:

Comment: I have added our schema above in my initial question. About your other questions:

MinMemory=0
MaxMemory=1TB (it was supposed to be 1.5TB-50GB)
phy. Memory= 1.5TB
The available space for TempDB is 700GB - thought in a worst case scenario, we could crete a TempDB-data file on the data file-disk (after shrinking the DB, we would have 7TB of free disk space there as well)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with DROP_EXISTING. This settings does not change anything about what the index build does physically. The strange thing about this message is that SQL Server can run almost any query with limited memory (such as 1GB).

Comment: Btw, it might be a good idea to build into a fresh filegroup. Otherwise you will have 2x temporary space usage in the existing FG and end up with a 4TB space at the beginning of the file where the old index was.

Comment: I never suspected DROP_EXISTING. The title is "Does the thing I do use the bufferpool for the recreated index?" and the thing I do was using “CREATE INDEX [...] WITH ( DROP_EXISTING, [...] )”. We have the FAIL_BUFFER_ALLOCATION and I do not know where it comes from. Unfortunately it is reproducable, but only in Prod and I wasn't involved in it until now. So I cannot collect data until the next try, which is supposed to be not some "try" but a "succeed"! Shifting 4TB into some other filegroup is not an option, as the impact would be to big and we won't get it acknowledged by the customer.

Comment: @DennisWinter - did you get this resolved?

Comment: The problem did not occur anymore, but I'm pretty sure just by accident.
By now, I'm pretty sure it was due to not having updated to the latest CU.

I tried to get management to upgraded to a higher CU, thought it was denied.